# Simple Regex Match - two pages with similar string

Tags: regex

Best way to match 2 pages for Google analytics.

Pages to Query:

1.) this_google.html 
2.) this_print_google.html

This is what I got so far: **/this_|print_|google.html/g**

Seems like there is a better way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
/this_(print_)?google.html/
```